# jQuery toggleClass not always animating

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, toggleclass

I'm trying to use jQuery's toggleClass for a news ticker type thing, and it works for the most part, but intermitantly it doesn't animate. Here is the code I have:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

     // ...other jQuery code

     setInterval('$("#stat-slider").toggleClass("all-time", 1000);', 10000);

 }
```

The first time the page loads, it flicks between the two states quickly, then runs as normal, except that sometimes it doesn't animate. Can anyone see anything that would cause this?

Many thanks.

P.S. Happens in FireFox and Internet Explorer 9

Comment: Can you include some more of your code ... HTML / JS / CSS ... or even better create a http://jsfiddle.net/ Thanks ..

Comment: toggleClass() doesnt take a numberic value as a parameter -> http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it doesn't work correctly because of the number you entered in toggleClass.
Try it without number like this:

`setInterval('$("#stat-slider").toggleClass("all-time");', 10000);`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use the delay function ...

```
function bla(){
  $("#stat-slider").show().delay(10000).queue(function (){
     $(this).toggleClass("all-time", 1000).unqueue();
     bla();
  });

}
```